# How to implements publish/subscribed with DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I need to implement a publish/subscribe with DynamoDB. Every of my cloud node should send events to all other nodes of my application that are connected to the same DynamoDB database. A typical use case is to clear caches if data in the database has changed.

Can be the DynamoDB streams a solution for it? It look for me that the stream can consumed only once and not from every other node. Is this right?

Is there some like tailed cursor support in DynamoDB?

Are there any other feature that I can use?

Comment: This is really a design question and not quite suited for SO main.  -- however. Dynamo is best when you need to quickly access data and know exactly what you will have. There is nothing like tailed cursor support because each item in dynamo is its own document, and has no relation to any others *other* than the partition key, which is basically that - a partition of data to make access quicker.  If you need something more cache like, Dynamo isnt really the solution. -- I would guess however that what *might* work is a cloud stream to a lambda to a SNS topic that your other nodes subscribe to.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB doesn't support Pub/Sub as a feature like you might see in Redis.

If you need to have cache functionality, you can check [DynamoDB Accelerator (Dax)](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/). You can check specifically the [consistency best practices documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.consistency.html).

You can also use a dedicated Pub/Sub service such as [Simple Notification Service (SNS)](https://aws.amazon.com/pub-sub-messaging/).